# Configuring Arduino to use external ADC reference for Analog inputs through MATLAB support package

Tags: arduino, analog, adc, matlab, voltage-reference

I am using the MATLAB support package for Arduino.

However, I need to configure the ADC reference to external. MATLAB documentation doesn't really explain how to do this?

Is there any way I can use the MATLAB support package and configure the Analog pins to use external ADC reference?

Comment: This doesn't work? https://se.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/arduino/ref/analoginput.html

Comment: That one uses the "Simulink support package for Arduino" which is distinct from the "MATLAB support package for Arduino"